# Increase Volume of an MKV Video from Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, audio, video-editing

I've got a large amount of .MKV video files which seem to all play at a very low volume - I end up having to turn the TV up all the way to hear them, which is really irritating when I switch to another channel and wake the dead because it's so loud.

**What I'm looking for is a command-line method to increase the volume** (so I can run it on all of them quickly) that would hopefully work regardless of the audio codec in use in the particular file. (I don't mind hard-coding the output audio though).

For reference, I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 on my server, and the files are being played back with Boxee on a Mac Mini, but the volume problem is the same on Windows too.

Comment: Since normalizing is often increasing the volume, check out this post; I use `ffmpeg-normalize` all the time, and it's easy to download with `pip`; it takes the guesswork out of using ffmpeg manually on the CLI: https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 29):

It isn't very well documented, but [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) has a `-vol` switch which will allow you to increase volume output.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mkv -vol 512 -vcodec copy output.mkv
```

Some things to take note of:

- the `-vol` switch uses "byte percent", so you can't just specify a 200% volume increase, 100% = 256 so specifying 256 would leave the volume as is, 512 would double it and so on.

Comment: Trying to test this out... looks like I need to re-compile ffmpeg from source to use matroska. Will report back!

Comment: I'll cross my fingers :)

Comment: Best solution ever and in 2018, it works out-of-the-box!

Comment: Is there also a way to normalize the volume?

Comment: For normalization this should be the right place to look: https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg

Comment: `-vol has been deprecated. Use the volume audio filter instead.`

Answer (score 12):

The -vol switch is deprecated I've found this method to be useful currently:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec copy -filter:a "volume=5.000000" output.louder.mkv`

Adjust the number after volume= to suit your needs.

You can also use decibel measures. To increase the volume by 15dB:
`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec copy -filter:a "volume=15dB" output.louder.mkv`

The -vcodec copy simply copies the video as is and -filter:a tells ffmpeg to filter the audio. Note that -vcodec can be shortened to -c:v

Sources:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioVolume

Testing.