# Put loudness of many video files to the same level

Tags: audio, video, video-editing

I have a bunch of video files, and in some videos the sound is **loud**, in the others—**not**. So a user has to change the volume of her player when she watches these videos in the playlist. I want *to level out* the loudness in every video, so it's the same everywhere. How can I do it?

The videos contain human voices. All sound streams are in *MPEG Layer-3* format. I will upload them on Youtube so playing with the settings of the player doesn't help.

Comment: Might help to say what format these videos are, in case the solution is specific to that format

Comment: Some video players have a setting for "Normalize" volume, which will make the player volume goes up and down as needed depends on how loud / soft it is. It is not perfect, but it will do the job if you don't want to edit the videos. 
If you are happy to go video editing frenzy, you can do it as well.

Comment: Are you using a program to edit/encode the videos?  If so then look for a normalize option (ideally EBU R128 loudness normalization) in that program.  If you don't want to re-encode anything, many formats have a way to add a tag that asks the player to adjust the gain by a specified amount.

Comment: There's a discussion how to do it [here](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/255147-Mini-Guide-Normalizing-Audio-for-Multiple-AVI-files). This might not solve your problems if the videos have long silent parts. Running the video audio through a compressor might work better. I really like [Stereotool](http://www.stereotool.com) which has a command line option.

Comment: What operating system are you doing this on? Would this work for you? [How can I normalize audio using ffmpeg?](http://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: @576i: Those BAT scripts have actually helped.

Answer (score -1):

What you would want to do in this case is a Batch Encode on all of your files that you need to adjust the volume on, except re-encode them all with the same format and settings as they originally were- but change the audio portion of the encode. Most software should allow you to do this; Adobe Media Encoder CS6 allows you to set a fixed audio gain/volume for the videos you are encoding, and during the encode each video's audio will be normalized to this level. I'm sure many other softwares have this feature- software such as Handbrake or Apple Compresser.

Comment: What about *VirtualDub*? I have tried it--it doesn't change the volume. There are not many settings at all, and it doesn't adjust the volume. The only way is to use special setting for the volume and adjust it yourself for every file. (I don't even need the *batch mode*, I can do it by hands.)

Comment: I Myself have never used this VirtualDub software, though from the quick research I just conducted, it seems to be more for capture and processing of footage rather than full encoding. again, I would advise Handbrake or Media Encoder- Handbrake is free, as well.

Comment: I Mentioned Batch Mode because it makes it extremely easy to apply the same modification- in this case volume normalization- to many files, at one time, completely automated.

Comment: I've tried *Handbrake*, it doesn't change the volume of the videos. The word *normalization* is not even mentioned in the software."

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DY-XfJzo3wQ