# Can ffmpeg apply audio gain losslessly?

Tags: ffmpeg

I came across this answer

[How can I normalize audio using ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/q/323119/#323127)

However this involves transcoding the audio stream. I know that programs like

- [MP3Gain](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net)
- [AACGain](http://aacgain.altosdesign.com)

can adjust the volume losslessly, that is to say without transcoding the file.
Can FFmpeg do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Lossless Gain?

No, ffmpeg cannot apply lossless audio gain methods like ReplayGain. You have to convert the audio, and if you want it to stay lossless, you have to output to a lossless file (e.g. PCM WAV, FLAC, …).

That said, ffmpeg at least supports *reading* the ReplayGain data.

#### Using ReplayGain while encoding

ffmpeg supports ReplayGain in the [`volume` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#volume). If you read a file with ReplayGain metadata and convert it, you can use the ReplayGain side data to adjust the volume:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af volume=replaygain=track output.wav
```

Here, the `track` volume is used. There is also `album`. Note that the default is to ignore ReplayGain.

---

#### Reading ReplayGain data

If you want to read out ReplayGain data, you can just use the [`replaygain` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#replaygain):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af replaygain -f null /dev/null
```

Example output:

```
Input #0, mp3, from 'apev2-track-only.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.93, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 151 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 151 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (mp3float) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to '/dev/null':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.16.100
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc60.31.102 pcm_s16le
[Parsed_replaygain_0 @ 0x6000029e0d10] track_gain = +13.69 dB
[Parsed_replaygain_0 @ 0x6000029e0d10] track_peak = 0.084451
```

Comment: by looking at ffmpeg filters documentation(https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#replaygain) i can see : replaygain_preamp flag . is that might be replaygain normalization with ffmpeg ?

Comment: Is this still true? http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2699#comment:12

Comment: @StevenPenny From what I understand, FFmpeg can only read ReplayGain info and apply it while using the volume filter, but not actually calculate it or write it as a metadata value.

Comment: @slhck Can `ffmpeg` v6 calculate and write `ReplayGain` metadata by now ?

Comment: @SebMa No, it can only parse and use it for volume adjustments, not actually calcualte it. I did update the answer though since at the time I wrote it, parsing was not supported.