# How do I use the normalize video filter with FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to run a video processing command with the [normalize filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#normalize) with FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf normalize=blackpt=black:whitept=white:smoothing=0 output.mp4
```

but I am getting this error:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7ff222e03280] No such filter: 'normalize'
```

I tried reinstalling FFMPEG with all the flags enabled but this did not solve the problem. I cannot found the normalize filter if I run `ffmpeg -filters`.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which version of ffmpeg are you using?

Comment: Also, a quick skim of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/323127/86708) suggests possible alternatives.

Comment: I'm using version 3.4.1. That linked answer refers to a different filter (to be used with audio). I'm trying to use the video normalize filter which is linked in the question: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#normalize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a current (git) version. The `3.4` series dates from mid-Oct 2017 and the filter was added in late November. All minor version upgrades `3.4.x` won't contain new features.

Either compile the latest snapshot or get binaries from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: Thank you. This worked, although now that I can run the normalize function, it doesn't actually work for me. I'll add a separate question for that.