# ffmpeg loudnorm results in ... not very loud

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, volume-mixer

I'm mixing together 27 separate video (and audio) streams, and I'm trying to use the loudnorm filter to set my output audio to a reasonable level.

I run the loudnorm filter in two passes using information I read [here](https://gist.github.com/kylophone/84ba07f6205895e65c9634a956bf6d54), for the first pass the filters look like this:

```
[0:a]volume=0.90,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud0]
[1:a]volume=2.08,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud1]
[2:a]volume=1.48,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud2]
[3:a]volume=2.53,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud3]
[4:a]volume=1.34,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud4]
[5:a]volume=1.81,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud5]
[6:a]volume=1.19,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud6]
[7:a]volume=3.01,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud7]
[8:a]volume=1.61,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud8]
[9:a]volume=1.85,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud9]
[10:a]volume=1.92,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud10]
[11:a]volume=1.36,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud11]
[12:a]volume=3.05,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud12]
[13:a]volume=1.97,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud13]
[14:a]volume=2.93,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud14]
[15:a]volume=5.03,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud15]
[16:a]volume=4.03,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud16]
[17:a]volume=7.84,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud17]
[18:a]volume=29.81,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud18]
[19:a]volume=31.59,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud19]
[20:a]volume=6.00,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud20]
[21:a]volume=1.45,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud21]
[22:a]volume=1.75,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud22]
[23:a]volume=4.17,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud23]
[24:a]volume=2.83,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud24]
[25:a]volume=4.55,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud25]
[26:a]volume=2.66,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud26]
[aud0][aud1][aud2][aud3][aud4][aud5][aud6][aud7][aud8][aud9][aud10][aud11][aud12][aud13][aud14][aud15][aud16][aud17][aud18][aud19][aud20][aud21][aud22][aud23][aud24][aud25][aud26]amix=inputs=27[a]
[a]loudnorm=I=-24:LRA=11:tp=-2:print_format=json
```

And loudnorm reports this:

```
"input_i": "-29.92"
"input_tp": "-15.22"
"input_lra": "17.10"
"input_thresh": "-41.11"
"output_i": "-22.93"
"output_tp": "-7.56"
"output_lra": "12.20"
"output_thresh": "-33.57"
"normalization_type": "dynamic"
"target_offset": "-1.07"
```

so I run it again, using the values from the first pass of loudnorm:

```
[a]adelay=delays=200:all=1[b]
[b]loudnorm=linear=true:I=-24:LRA=11:tp=-2:measured_I=-29.92:measured_LRA=17.10:
   measured_tp=-15.22:measured_thresh=-41.11:offset=-1.07:print_format=summary[level]
[level]asplit[a1][a2]
```

I then re-attach the video (which has its own interesting processing) and audio:

```
-map "[video]" -map "[a1]" -c:v libx264 "output.mp4"  -map "[a2]" "output.mp3""
```

and the output video just seems really quiet to me.  I was trying to figure out a way to quantify that, and the only thing I've got is that when I drop it in Sony Movie Studio, the audio is clearly nowhere near as loud as it could be:

[image]

Am I calling loudnorm wrong somehow?

Comment: `I=-24` won't give you large amplitudes.

Comment: Aha!  I am retrying now with I=-16.  Do you know, are the values I pass to loudnorm during the first pass relevant at all (since I'm throwing away the output)?

Comment: -16 is definitely better, is -14 a more reasonable default (from https://youlean.co/loudness-standards-full-comparison-table/)?

Comment: also, youtube etc use `tp=-1`. (no idea what `LRA=11` means.)